# To Reset Field using Visualforce page and apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

Hi i am new to visual force i wanted to learn how to reset the field in VisualForce Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set immediate="true" on the reset button